# How can I call the mouse right click event in SwingGui?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have a table. If I right-click I got a JPopUpMenu but before the pop-up I want to select the row where the right-click event is done. Here is what I've tried.

```
path_tbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getPoint());

            Point point = e.getPoint();
            int selectedRow = path_tbl.rowAtPoint(point);
            path_tbl.setRowSelectionInterval(selectedRow, selectedRow);
        }
    });
```

In that event, I cannot get any output from the console when I right-click. However, when I left-click, points are printed to the console.

> java.awt.Point[x=105,y=76]

So, this event only works when I left-click. How can I make this event work with right-click?

Comment: How did you add a JPopupMenu to your table?  Did you use [setComponentPopupMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu))?

Comment: Yes, I used that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want custom mouse behavior, you should not use [setComponentPopupMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu)).

Instead, display the JPopupMenu yourself, using JPopupMenu’s [show](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show(java.awt.Component,int,int)) method:

```
JPopupMenu menu = /* ... */;

path_tbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    private void showPopupMenuFor(MouseEvent e) {
        if (menu.isPopupTrigger(e)) {
            Point point = e.getPoint();
            int row = path_tbl.rowAtPoint(point);

            if (!path_tbl.isRowSelected(row)) {
                path_tbl.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
            }

            menu.show(path_tbl, e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        showPopupMenuFor(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        showPopupMenuFor(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        showPopupMenuFor(e);
    }
});
```

You must check the MouseEvent in both mousePressed *and* mouseReleased, because exactly when a context menu is triggered depends on the platform and the look-and-feel.  (Checking in mouseClicked may or may not be necessary, but it doesn’t hurt.)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, I'm lazy, so if I don't need to do something, then I'd prefer not to.  In this case, I'd prefer to make use of the existing API works as much as possible, meaning, make use of [`JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu)), as it will take care of the "how" and "when" the popup should be shown, based on the current platform.

However, as you have discovered, by default, `JTable` will NOT select the row when the user presses the "right" mouse button, for that, you could just continue with your current workflow, but, checking to see if the `MouseEvent` is actually a "right" click.

Lucky for us, some of the original Swing developers were also "lazy" and they provided us with [`SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isRightMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)), yea

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 10);
            for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
                Vector data = new Vector(10);
                for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {

                    String value = row + "x" + ((char) (col + 'A'));
                    data.add(value);

                }
                model.addRow(data);
            }

            JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
            menu.add("Hello");
            menu.add("This looks interesting");
            menu.add("I like bi-planes");

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                        Point point = e.getPoint();
                        int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);

                        if (!table.isRowSelected(row)) {
                            table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

    }
}
```